# dimension of image of proper closed set under a morphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow \mathbb A^{n}$ be a finite surjective morphism ,where $X$ is irreducible affine variety and dim$X=n$ 
and $K$ be a proper closed subset of $X$.Can we conclude that dimension of $\pi(K)$ is strictly less than $n$ ?

I think that the dimension should be less than n,since $K$ is proper closed in $X$ so dimension has to be strictly less than n and $\pi(K)$ has to be a proper in $\mathbb A^{n}$ but not getting convinced .

Comment: Is your base-scheme Jacobson ?

Comment: I am sorry that i am not aware of base-scheme Jacobson?But I think now question is clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\pi$ is finite, $K$ and $\pi(K)$ have the same dimension.

Comment: sorry,I did not get your idea completely.I can show that if $\pi $ is finite surjective morphism from irreducible to irreducible ,then dim$X=$dim$Y$.But why should restriction of finite morphism finite?

Comment: Sorry I got your idea as restriction of a finite morphism on a closed set is finite.